Genetic algorithm for kubernetes allocation
I am trying to allocate Kubernetes pods to nodes using a genetic algorithm, where each pod is assigned to one node. Below is my implementation:
from string import ascii_lowercase
import numpy as np
import random
from itertools import compress
import math
import pandas as pd
import random

def create_pods_and_nodes(n_pods=40, n_nodes=15):
    # Create pod and node names
    pod = ['pod_' + str(i+1) for i in range(n_pods)]
    node = ['node_' + str(i+1) for i in range(n_nodes)]

    # Define CPU and RAM options
    cpu = [2**i for i in range(1, 8)]  # 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128
    ram = [2**i for i in range(2, 10)]  # 4, 8, 16, ..., 8192

    # Create the pods DataFrame
    pods = pd.DataFrame({
        'pod': pod,
        'cpu': random.choices(cpu[0:3], k=n_pods),  # Small CPU for pods
        'ram': random.choices(ram[0:4], k=n_pods),  # Small RAM for pods
    })

    # Create the nodes DataFrame
    nodes = pd.DataFrame({
        'node': node,
        'cpu': random.choices(cpu[4:len(cpu)-1], k=n_nodes),  # Larger CPU for nodes
        'ram': random.choices(ram[4:len(ram)-1], k=n_nodes),  # Larger RAM for nodes
    })

    return pods, nodes

# Example usage
pods, nodes = create_pods_and_nodes(n_pods=46, n_nodes=6)

# Display the results
print("Pods DataFrame:\n", pods.head())
print("\nNodes DataFrame:\n", nodes.head())

print(f"total CPU pods: {np.sum(pods['cpu'])}")
print(f"total RAM pods: {np.sum(pods['ram'])}")
print('\n')
print(f"total CPU nodes: {np.sum(nodes['cpu'])}")
print(f"total RAM nodes: {np.sum(nodes['ram'])}")

# Genetic Algorithm Parameters
POPULATION_SIZE = 100
GENERATIONS = 50
MUTATION_RATE = 0.1
TOURNAMENT_SIZE = 5

def create_individual():
    return [random.randint(0, len(nodes) - 1) for _ in range(len(pods))]

def create_population(size):
    return [create_individual() for _ in range(size)]

def fitness(individual):
    total_cpu_used = np.zeros(len(nodes))
    total_ram_used = np.zeros(len(nodes))
    unallocated_pods = 0

    for pod_idx, node_idx in enumerate(individual):
        pod_cpu = pods.iloc[pod_idx]['cpu']
        pod_ram = pods.iloc[pod_idx]['ram']

        if total_cpu_used[node_idx] + pod_cpu <= nodes.iloc[node_idx]['cpu'] and total_ram_used[node_idx] + pod_ram <= nodes.iloc[node_idx]['ram']:
            total_cpu_used[node_idx] += pod_cpu
            total_ram_used[node_idx] += pod_ram
        else:
            unallocated_pods += 1  # Count unallocated pods

    # Reward for utilizing resources and penalize for unallocated pods
    return (total_cpu_used.sum() + total_ram_used.sum()) - (unallocated_pods * 10)

def select(population):
    tournament = random.sample(population, TOURNAMENT_SIZE)
    return max(tournament, key=fitness)

def crossover(parent1, parent2):
    crossover_point = random.randint(1, len(pods) - 1)
    child1 = parent1[:crossover_point] + parent2[crossover_point:]
    child2 = parent2[:crossover_point] + parent1[crossover_point:]
    return child1, child2

def mutate(individual):
    for idx in range(len(individual)):
        if random.random() < MUTATION_RATE:
            individual[idx] = random.randint(0, len(nodes) - 1)

def genetic_algorithm():
    population = create_population(POPULATION_SIZE)
    
    for generation in range(GENERATIONS):
        new_population = []
        for _ in range(POPULATION_SIZE // 2):
            parent1 = select(population)
            parent2 = select(population)
            child1, child2 = crossover(parent1, parent2)
            mutate(child1)
            mutate(child2)
            new_population.extend([child1, child2])
        population = new_population

        # Print the best fitness of this generation
        best_fitness = max(fitness(individual) for individual in population)
        print(f"Generation {generation + 1}: Best Fitness = {best_fitness}")

    # Return the best individual found
    best_individual = max(population, key=fitness)
    return best_individual

# Run the genetic algorithm
print("Starting Genetic Algorithm...")
best_allocation = genetic_algorithm()
print("Genetic Algorithm completed.\n")

# Create the allocation DataFrame
allocation_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Pod': pods['pod'],
    'Node': [nodes.iloc[best_allocation[i]]['node'] for i in range(len(best_allocation))],
    'Pod_Resources': [list(pods.iloc[i][['cpu', 'ram']]) for i in range(len(best_allocation))],
    'Node_Resources': [list(nodes.iloc[best_allocation[i]][['cpu', 'ram']]) for i in range(len(best_allocation))]
})

# Print the allocation DataFrame
print("\nAllocation DataFrame:")
print(allocation_df)

# Summarize total CPU and RAM utilization for each node
node_utilization_df = allocation_df.groupby('Node').agg(
    Total_CPU_Used=pd.NamedAgg(column='Pod_Resources', aggfunc=lambda x: sum([res[0] for res in x if res])),
    Total_RAM_Used=pd.NamedAgg(column='Pod_Resources', aggfunc=lambda x: sum([res[1] for res in x if res])),
    Node_CPU=pd.NamedAgg(column='Node_Resources', aggfunc=lambda x: x.iloc[0][0] if x.iloc[0] is not None else 0),
    Node_RAM=pd.NamedAgg(column='Node_Resources', aggfunc=lambda x: x.iloc[0][1] if x.iloc[0] is not None else 0)
)

# Calculate CPU and RAM utilization percentages for each node
node_utilization_df['CPU_Utilization'] = (node_utilization_df['Total_CPU_Used'] / node_utilization_df['Node_CPU']) * 100
node_utilization_df['RAM_Utilization'] = (node_utilization_df['Total_RAM_Used'] / node_utilization_df['Node_RAM']) * 100

# Print the total CPU and RAM utilization for each node
print("\nTotal CPU and RAM utilization for each node:")
print(node_utilization_df)

My implementation works if the total number of CPU and/or RAM of the pods is smaller than the total CPU and/or RAM of the nodes. However, I want to make it work even if the total CPU and/or RAM of the pods exceeds the total CPU and/or RAM of the nodes, allowing for unallocated pods if they cannot be assigned. How can I achieve this?
Any suggestions or improvements would be greatly appreciated!

This is a straightforward bin packing problem.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem  Why on earth would your tackle it with a genetic algorithm!?!  It is going to be horribly slow.

This is a straightforward bin packing problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem  Why tackle it with a genetic algorithm!?! That is going to be horribly slow, especially if you use python.
Implementing a standard bin packing algorithm in a native language with a decent optimizing compiler will give performance many orders of magnitude faster - a millisecond or two for your sample problem
Here is the C++ code for the implementation of the first-fit decreasing bin packing algorithm with dual resources
void pack()
{
    // sort items in order of decreasing largest resource requirement sum

    std::sort(
        theItems.begin(), theItems.end(),
        [](const cThing &a, const cThing &b) -> bool
        {
            int sa = a.myRes1 + a.myRes2;
            int sb = b.myRes1 + b.myRes2;
            return sa > sb;
        });

    // sort bins in order of increasing capacity sum

    std::sort(
        theBins.begin(), theBins.end(),
        [](const cThing &a, const cThing &b) -> bool
        {
            int sa = a.myRes1 + a.myRes2;
            int sb = b.myRes1 + b.myRes2;
            return sa < sb;
        });

    // fit each item into the smallest bin that fits
    
    for (cThing &item : theItems)
    {
        for (cThing &bin : theBins)
        {
            if (item.myRes1 > bin.myRes1 ||
                item.myRes2 > bin.myRes2)
            continue;

            bin.pack( item );

            break;
        }
    }
}

The output for a run:
All iems packed
node_3 contains: pod_1 pod_21
node_13 contains: pod_19 pod_15
node_11 contains: pod_31 pod_7
node_10 contains: pod_8 pod_28 pod_24 pod_17 pod_32
node_14 contains: pod_16 pod_36 pod_30 pod_29 pod_6 pod_34 pod_22 pod_9 pod_20 pod_38
node_15 contains: pod_37 pod_12 pod_13 pod_25 pod_26 pod_4 pod_3 pod_33 pod_27 pod_35 pod_2 pod_39 pod_23 
node_4 contains: pod_5 pod_18 pod_14 pod_11 pod_10 pod_40
node_9 is empty
node_1 is empty
node_8 is empty
node_7 is empty
node_5 is empty
node_12 is empty
node_2 is empty
node_6 is empty

The above run uses the setup posted in the question.
You added:

I want to make it work even if the total CPU and/or RAM of the pods
exceeds the total CPU and/or RAM of the nodes, allowing for
unallocated pods if they cannot be assigned. How can I achieve this?

So I reduce the number of nodes created ( from 15 to 4 ) so that not all pods can be fitted.  Below is the result of this run showing that the code handles this naturally
pod_12 pod_25 pod_26 pod_4 pod_3 pod_33 pod_27 pod_35 pod_2 pod_39 pod_5 pod_23 pod_18 pod_14 pod_11 pod_10 pod_40
17 items did not fit
node_3 contains: pod_1 pod_21
node_4 contains: pod_19 pod_15 pod_31 pod_7
node_1 contains: pod_8 pod_28 pod_24 pod_17 pod_32 pod_16 pod_36 pod_30 pod_29 pod_6 pod_34
node_2 contains: pod_22 pod_9 pod_20 pod_38 pod_37 pod_13

Complete application code at https://github.com/JamesBremner/so79049807

Indeed this implementation works, but the algorithm leaves a lots of pods unallocated despite that there might be a node where it could be allocated.

I did not explain that well, sorry.  There are two runs shown in my answer.  The first run has 15 nodes and all the pods are allocated successfully.  The second run the number of nodes is reduced to 4, so that 17 pods remain unallocated.  I believe this is what your question was about.

@AndCh Answer edited to clarify that the results show TWO runs, one with a reduced number of nodes.
